# gulp-babel shown Syntax-error on comments

Tags: webpack, gulp, gulp-babel

I help on developping a Foss tool , but i have error in gulp on Fedora29. Other dev use debian based system and seems it's OK. 
It was OK with the previopus version of Fedora

The gulp files are [at github](https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/tree/master/assets/packages/adminbasics) and it seems gulp-babel throw SyntaxError on comment :

```
[15:02:50] SyntaxError in plugin "run-sequence(babelify)"
Message:
    /var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/build/adminbasics.js: Unexpected token (26258:37)
Details:
    pos: 811003
    loc: [object Object]
    _babel: true
    codeFrame:   26256 | 
  26257 |           if (context.method === "throw") {
> 26258 |             // If maybeInvokeDelegate
        |                                      ^
    fileName: /var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/build/adminbasics.js
```

Here the complete result of gulp default

```
[adminbasics]$ gulp --no-color default
[15:02:42] Using gulpfile /var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/gulpfile.js
[15:02:42] Starting 'default'...
[15:02:42] Starting 'compile:production'...
[15:02:42] Starting 'sass:production'...
[15:02:42] Starting 'webpack:production'...
[15:02:42] Finished 'sass:production' after 154 ms
[15:02:42] Version: webpack 3.12.0
             Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    adminbasics.js   871 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
adminbasics.js.map  1.12 MB       0  [emitted]         main
[15:02:42] Finished 'webpack:production' after 894 ms
[15:02:42] Starting 'compress'...
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/build/adminbasics.js" as it exceeds the max of "500KB".
[15:02:49] Finished 'compress' after 6.85 s
[15:02:49] Starting 'compresslibs'...
[15:02:49] Finished 'compresslibs' after 4.19 ms
[15:02:49] Finished 'compile:production' after 7.75 s
[15:02:49] Starting 'sass'...
[15:02:49] Starting 'webpack'...
[15:02:49] Starting 'babelify'...
[15:02:49] Finished 'sass' after 59 ms
[15:02:50] Version: webpack 3.12.0
             Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    adminbasics.js   871 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
adminbasics.js.map  1.12 MB       0  [emitted]         main
[15:02:50] 'babelify' errored after 889 ms
[15:02:50] SyntaxError in plugin "gulp-babel"
Message:
    /var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/build/adminbasics.js: Unexpected token (26258:37)
[15:02:50] 'default' errored after 8.65 s
[15:02:50] SyntaxError in plugin "run-sequence(babelify)"
Message:
    /var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/build/adminbasics.js: Unexpected token (26258:37)
Details:
    pos: 811003
    loc: [object Object]
    _babel: true
    codeFrame:   26256 | 
  26257 |           if (context.method === "throw") {
> 26258 |             // If maybeInvokeDelegate
        |                                      ^
    fileName: /var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/build/adminbasics.js

Stack:
SyntaxError: /var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/build/adminbasics.js: Unexpected token (26258:37)
  26256 | 
  26257 |           if (context.method === "throw") {
> 26258 |             // If maybeInvokeDelegate
        |                                      ^
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (/var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1761:8)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3750:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3494:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3474:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3404:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3381:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3344:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (/var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3306:19)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/var/www/master/assets/packages/adminbasics/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1906:19)
[15:02:50] Finished 'webpack' after 905 ms
```

My version

```
$ gulp -v
[16:09:58] CLI version 2.0.1
[16:09:58] Local version 3.9.1
```

Thanks if anyone can give advice.

Comment: OK : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34592776/2239406 starting point, but it's not css here …

Comment: Did you found a solution to this?

Comment: No, and updated to fedora 31 + move to a debian on QEMU for compiling.